# How to create 2 rows per item in a dynamic column dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dynamic-columns

I have this dynamic column dataTable, and I want to have one column rowspan=2 and the other column 2 rows:

```
    <p:column headerText="Chapter Name" style="width:80px" rowspan="2" >
        <p:inputText value="#{bookVar.name}" style="width:80px;" id="name"  />
    </p:column>

    <p:columns id="templateTable" value="#{bookBean.tableColHeaderList}" var="colHeader" columnIndexVar="colIndex"  > 
        <f:facet name="header"> #{colHeader.header}</f:facet>

        <p:row>
                <p:inputText value="#{bookVar.chapterList[colIndex].answer}" style="width:10px;" id="answer" tabindex="1" maxlength="1" onblur="value=value.toUpperCase()" onkeyup="$(this).next().focus();" />
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
                <p:inputText value="#{bookVar.chapterList[colIndex].officialAnswer}" style="width:10px;" id="officialAnswer" tabindex="2" maxlength="1" onblur="value=value.toUpperCase()" onkeyup="$(this).next().focus();" />
        </p:row>
    </p:columns>
```

The way I did it  it is not working. Each dynamic column (with both inputText) is in one TD How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**: changing the question a little - is it possible in a dataTable with dynamic columns, to have 2 rows for each item?

**EDIT2**: I have already tried using p:column inside my p:row

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic columns is used when you don't know for sure how many columns you need to render. Is that true in your case ?

Comment: Yes it is my case. The quantity of columns depends on another field.

Comment: check the primefaces manual/showcase. they have a few examples for dynamic columns.

Comment: But my code is working... they don't have examples for my special case: each row for the dataTable is actually 2 rows. So I'd like 2 <tr> for the dynamic columns, and for the other column just one <tr> using rowspan = 2, and what I'm getting is just one <tr> for all columns

Comment: you need to have a  <p:column> inside your <p:row>

Comment: I have already tried, same thing.

Comment: Why not just put a `<br/>` between the two inputs instead of using `<p:row>`?

Comment: Well, what I really want to do is to get this: `onkeyup="$(this).next().focus();"` working properly. The way it is now, it is going to the next element in the same TD, while I need it to go to the next top element in the next TD.